# Why is the copy constructor being called here?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    int x;
public:

    A(int a)
    {   
        x = a;
        cout << "CTOR CALLED";
    }
    A(A &t)
    {
        cout << "COPY CTOR CALLED";
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << "Random stuff";
    }
    A operator = (A &d)
    {   
        d.x = x;
        cout << "Assignment operator called";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a(3), b(4);
    a = b;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is :

> CTOR CALLED
>   CTOR CALLED
>   Assignment operator called
>   COPY CTOR CALLED

When I used the watch in visual studio it showed that the value of `x` in `a` had been changed even before the overloaded assignment operator was called.

So why is the copy constructor even being called here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SomeProgrammerDude already said, it's because you return by value, not by reference like you usually do with an assignment operator. I would like to add that your assignment operator is currently the wrong way around:

```
A operator = (A &d)
{   
    d.x = x;
    cout << "Assignment operator called";
    return *this;
}
```

Usually you pass `d` by const reference because we want to alter the members of `this`. You are changing the members of `d`. Which would functionally turn your `a = b;` into `b = a;` since `a = b;` is actually changing members of `b` now !

Making `d` a `const&` prevents these mistakes.

You should change it to:

```
A& operator = (A const &d)
{   
    x = d.x;
    cout << "Assignment operator called";
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because you return *by value* from the assignment operator. It should return a *reference*:

```
A& operator = (A &d) { ... }
```

Comment: Just a note the parameter should be const ref  `A& operator = (A const &d) { ... }`  Same for the copy constructor.

Comment: And you want to copy the value of `x` other way around. I.e. `x = d.x;`